# Define a set of arcs based on the arrangements of a permutation

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, permutations

Let $T$ be a permutation (multiset). A function $\pi(i)$ assigns a positive integer value lower than $m$ for an element $i$ of $T$. The set $B_k$ is a subset of $T$, such that $i \in B_k$ if $\pi(i) = k$, i.e. $B_k = \{ i \in T : \pi(i) = k \}$. Note that the arrangement of the elements in $B_k$ are the same as $T$. Let $Y$ be a set of arcs $(i,j)$, where an arc exist for each element $i$ to $i+1$ of $Y_k$, for all $k$ and $i < |Y_k$ , e.g. $Y = \{ (Y_{k,i}, Y_{k,i+1}) : k \leq m \land i < |Y_k| \}$.

My question is, is it clear the way that I am writing? There is an easier way to make the reader understand those relations? Could I reduce the amount of text by using a more clear set builder notation?

Comment: What is $\pi$?  What do you mean by $T = \{ 3, 1, 2 \}$  This is a set, not a permutation.  I can't follow what you mean at all.

Comment: $\pi(i)$ is a function that returns an integer, and I mentioned that $T$ is a permutation, therefore we are talking about multisets, not a set. The set, in this case, would be $V = \{1, 2, 3\}$, where permutation $T = \{ 3, 1, 2\}$, represent one possible arrangement of $V$.

Comment: What I mean by $pi()$ is that, if we had a permutation $\{ 3, 1, 5, 4, 2\}$, such that $\pi(1) = \pi(2) = \pi(3) = 1$ and  $\pi(4) = \pi(5) = 2$, then $Y = \{ (3,1), (1,2), (5,4)\}$. Is it clear now?

Comment: Not completely.  Why is $(3,2)\notin Y\text{ and } (1,2)\in Y$?  It   seems like the three arcs $(1,2),(1,3),(3,2)$ are all possible, and any two of them determine the third.  Is there some canonical selection, or will any two be acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

The elements where $\pi$ takes the same value form an equivalence class.  You can identify them with the [union-find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) algorithm. Once you have identified the equivalence classes, you can sort them with the key being their original position in the list.  You can them make the arcs according to whatever protocol you are using.  The simplest of course would be the first with the second, the second with the third, and so on.

It may be true that the sorting step will be unnecessary, due to the order in which the elements are processed by union-find.  You should check this.

Comment: Based on my last example, with $T = \{3,1,5,4,2\}$, you mean that I should define subsets $T_1 = \{ 3,2,1\}$, and $T_2 = \{ 5, 4\}$. Then I can define arcs ($T_{ij}, T_{ij+1}$) for all $i$ and $j < |T_i|$.

Comment: @WillEnsaba Yes, that's what I mean, and that's what I thought you had in mind.

Comment: I kind had it in mind but it was not very clear. I was also wondering if I could summarize it into one or two equations rather than one entire paragraph of text. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to be of help.